# How do I transfer a GET-Parameter from one cshtml-page to another in a URL-Format?

Tags: c#, razor

my code:

start.cshtml:

```
<a href="Page2.cshtml?parameter=one">link</a>
```

Page2.cshtml:

```
Request.Params["parameter"]
```

the get-parameter seems not to get transfered from the start-page to the page2, because when i try to display "parameter" on Page2, i get the error it's empty.

how can i solve this?

Comment: is this mvc? generally in mvc, you use an action.

Comment: my professor said i should generate the link by my own in URL: Page2.cshtml?parameter=one

Answer (score 0):

You create a link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("link", "Action", "Controller", new { parameter="one" }) %>
```

For mvc core

```
<a asp-controller="Controller" asp-action="Action" asp-route-parameter="one" >link</a>
```

Then you need to have an action receiving this parameter:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Action(string parameter)
{
    ViewBag.parameter = parameter;
    return View()
}
```

And in your view you just show this parameter:

```
<label>Parameter:</label>  @ViewBag.parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve without the helper class intentionally,then below is the working code for you

```
syntax:
<a href="ControllerName/Action(or)PageName?parameter=one">link</a>

Example:
<a href="yourcontrollername/Page2?parameter=one">link</a>
```

Note : just give the action/view name alone ie page2 , should not specify as page.cshtml.

Hope it will be helpful ,kindly let me know your thoughts or feedbacks

thanks
karthik

Comment: where can i find my controllername? why not specify it with "page2.cshtml"? my professor said i should generate the link by my own in URL: Page2.cshtml?parameter=one